# RStudio Plots pane (copying to a Word document)

Tags: r, rstudio

Creating a decision tree in Rattle, plots in RStudio, but when zoomed in and using "copy image", it is illegible in a Word document. Can the plot be exported?

I used the left-click on the mouse and copy image. At first I took screenshots but the instructor said they were too small. In other papers the decision trees are readable. In mine they are not. I did email the instructor and posted in the classes General Questions but I have not received a response. Incidentally, the class is over. I got a B but thought in an actual job the plot would need to be better. I only had this problem with decision trees-not box plots or distribution plots.

There isn't any code? I had to use Rattle's GUI Interface and then the plot was generated in RStudio.

In example papers, the plots looked "normal". In my Word documents, the plot was too small. I'm new to R and not sure if there is a way to export a plot.

Comment: Did you try clicking the `Export` button in the plots pane? Or in the Plots menu, the option `Save As Image`

Comment: Is your question just whether you can export an image from RStudio? There's a lot happening in this question but no code or anything for us to see, so it's pretty muddled.

Comment: Yes-I have no code because the plot was generated through Rattle. So I executed (basically pushed buttons) in Rattle and a decision tree was plotted in RStudio. In RStudio it looks fine, but I tried just copying it, then exporting it and it shrunk. And looking at the console or history, the only last code in loading Rattle, library(rattle).

Comment: Yes, after I posted the question, I thought, just do that and it will be a pdf file. The pdf file looked fine but inserting into Word, it shrunk again. I googled a bit and found an article with this code:

Comment: You forgot the code in your last comment, although it should really be an [edit] to the question. But I really don't know that there's a way for folks to help debug code if there isn't any. Maybe look through the docs for Rattle?

Comment: I don't know the code. It is supposed to be in R (according to Rattle, where I'm just pushing buttons), but in the history all there is is loading Rattle. I did look for Rattle and found nothing. Nothing on Google or any other blog. I'm waiting on the instructor, but the class is over so, not sure.